# Fetch specific data from external api in React JS

Tags: json, reactjs, api, rest

I am trying to fetch profile data from an external api in react. the fetch works, but it brings all data at once. If i call for username, the code gives the list of username instead of one username. How to get specific fetch request by this code? is there any way to dynamicly generate id for call?

Here is the code i tried

```
export default class About extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items:[],
      isLoaded: false,
    }
  }
    componentDidMount(){

      fetch('http://___.com/api/users/')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then (json => {
                this.setState({
                  isLoaded: true,
                  items: json,
                })
        })
    }
  render() {
      var { isLoaded , items } = this.state;
      if (!isLoaded) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>;
      }
      else
          <div>
            Data has been loaded
          </div>

    return (
          <div>
            <ul>
              {items.map(item => (
                    <li key={item.id}>
                      Name: {item.username}
                    </li>
              ))};
            </ul>
          </div>
    ) 
  }
}
```

note that, the json data in the api has "id" and "username" field and the fetch works for bringing all data at once.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
componentDidMount(){
          

  fetch('http://___.com/api/users/')
    .then(res => 
      if (res.ok) {
            this.setState({
              isLoaded: true,
              items: res.json(),
            })
   })
}
```

Comment: doesn't work. the if loop gets an error for being called in a function i think

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters in the request body to let the server know what you are seeking exactly .
in your case you can use something like this:

```
      fetch('http://___.com/api/users/',{
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify({
                id: 'userId'
                })})
```

According to [react official docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/network/)

Comment: This is not working, the error is saying "GET/POST method cannot have a body". This may work on api without get/post i guess

Comment: do you know what is the request type that your API accepts? I edited the code, try it again and tell me the result. I added POST method to the fetch options. if your server accepts GET requests change that 'POST' to 'GET'

Comment: tried the code. still same error. it either gives the whole list or nothing at all

Comment: I doubt maybe the problem is from your api? did you try querying with postman from your API?

Comment: the problem is not with the api. the api works fine i checked